# How to get underlying variable from Go custom type

Tags: go

I'm trying to abstract the use of gorequest by only importing my own libraries into the main code and using a helper to download a page using [gorequest](http://godoc.org/github.com/parnurzeal/gorequest#Response). The `.End()` method returns a gorequest.Response, a string (containing the body) and a slice of errors if present.

The `gorequest.Response` it's just an `http.Response` declared as `type Response *http.Response`

In order to prevent importing the library into other go files, how could I get the underlying `http.Response` from the `gorequest.Response` type?

Comment: Either way you'll have to reference the other package. If you put a function to cast it and return it in the other package - then you need to reference it to call the function. If you create a local function, you need to reference the package to access the type anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I should reference `net/http` in order to read the http.Response, but I've already referenced that package so there's no much to modify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that `gorequest.Response` is just a pointer to `http.Response` so you could do something like:

```
var response http.Response
response = *gorequest.Response
```

And that should help you pass it as a pointer.